# Javascript - regular expression - how to skip search for a string that exists within a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

In code below, using regex, how do we search and replace the "=" that is NOT found within <> with ":"

```
'ABC=<ATTR1 TEST="11">VALUE1</ATTR1>'
```

Comment: Using an XML parser and then applying your replacement only to text nodes might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is not really what regex is designed for, but...

```
(?<!<[^>]*)=(?![^<]*>)
```

is about as close as you'd get with regex (if your flavor supported negative lookahead and lookbehind). However, I don't believe Javascript does, which means that you should really be using a more specific parser than a regex engine.

Comment: Javascript does only support look ahead, but not look behind. Anyway +1

Comment: Make that "if your flavor supported negative *variable length* lookahead and lookbehind". ;-) And even if it did, this wouldn't work, since it does not handle quotes, -1.

Comment: @Qtax - hence the "about as close as you'd get". Regex *can't* handle quotes properly.

Comment: Sure it can, quotes are not the problem when it comes to parsing HTML with regex. ;-)

Comment: In order to properly handle quotes, you need to know if you're in a tag. In order to properly handle tags, you need to be able to nest. In order to nest, you need a non-regular language.

Comment: First, this isn't formal language theory, almost all of todays regex flavors are not regular, they haven't been since at least the introduction of backreferences. Second, lexing the tags themselves is easily done with regex, even if only formal language theory regular expression rules are used. Limited levels of "nesting" is what regex are made for, arbitrary levels, recursion, that is what makes things more tricky, but still possible with modern regex flavors.

Comment: "Regex can't handle quotes properly", see my answer. No lookarounds, only the simplest of rules used. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a cross browser solution (lookbehind is a no go)

1. I would just store all text between `<>` with a regex into an array
2. Do your equal/`=` replace
3. Lastly I would restore the text between `<>`

Alternatively you could `split().reverse()` the string in javascript and then use lookahead to get around not having lookbehind support.  [This](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript) article also provides some alternative solutions to having look behind support.

Comment: `foo=<bar baz="5 > 3 = true"></bar>`

Comment: He sad not found between <> therefore you code doesn't qualify.  Also if you had code like you posted you could store all strings prior to to storing the <>.  You could also support escaping the `"`/`'` using the lookbehind trick.

Answer (score 0):

**You *should not parse HTML with regex*, instead use a parser. See mu's comment.**

This works if you only have these kinds of tags, and the text contains no unescaped `<` or `>`:

```
var str = 'ABC=<ATTR1 TEST="11">VALUE1</ATTR1>'+"\n"
    + 'foo = bar <foo x="5 > 3 = true" y=\'fo> = \'> === </foo=>';

str = str.replace(/(?:=|(<(?:[^"'<>]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>))/g, function(m,tag){
    return tag ? tag : ':';
});
```

Result:

```
ABC:<ATTR1 TEST="11">VALUE1</ATTR1>
foo : bar <foo x="5 > 3 = true" y='fo> = '> ::: </foo=>
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/Vz6BK/

I wrote this just for fun, I did not think of all cases, just a proof of concept.

Comment: This would fail on the first escaped quote it came across (`<foo bar="baz\"qux">`).

Comment: Because there are no such escapes in HTML, you escape it by using `&quot;`.

Comment: Thanks for the code Amber and Qtax! You guys are great! But umm, could you please make us understand how we arrive at 
`/(?:=|(<(?:[^"'<>]+|"[^"]*"|'[^']*')*>))/g`
It's kinda mind-boggling!

Comment: @Aman, that matches a `=` or a complete tag, so that any possible `=` in the tag will not be changed.